# How can i get data from server?

Tags: android, json

after running the url i am getting data in the following form

```
[
  {
    "user_name": "riz",
    "gems_available": "10",
    "free_gems": "110"
  },
  {
    "match_name": "ausvsind",
    "Match_start_time": "2016-03-27  19:00:56",
    "season_name": "Mid-Season"
  }
]
```

now i want to get user_name and all the data but unable to do..i am getting this data in the result after running my app but unable to fetch.below i have my java code.please help me where i am wrong.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();    
jsonObj.put("user_id", "abc@hotmail.com");
jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put(jsonObj);

final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(USER_URL);

String str = jsonArray.toString().replace("[", "");
String str1 = str.replace("]", "");

httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(str1.toString()));
resp = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity ent = resp.getEntity();

result = EntityUtils.toString(ent);
jsonArray1.put(result);

jsobj = new JSONObject(result);
us1 = jsobj.getString(TAG_USER_NAME);
us2 = jsobj.getString(TAG_GEMS_AVAILABLE);
us3 = jsobj.getString(TAG_GEMS_FREE);
```

Comment: can anyone please help me?

Comment: I just want to say that the answers promoting libraries rather than attempting to answer the question are not helpful at all. They don't highlight problems in your thinking, and their abstraction will make it that much harder to realize. First get the basic concept of a json parse down. Once you are comfortable with what a Json Object and Array are, then use GSON.

Comment: Suggestion: Use retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Retrofit : it helps you parse JSON into a java POJO automagically and will help you avoid non-differential boilerplate

https://github.com/square/retrofit

Answer (score 0):

Why are you removing the "[" and "]" characters? Those are part of the JSONArray? If you did not want them there, use a JSONObject instead.

I did not test this, so it will have some issues. Conceptually this should work for you:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("user_id", "abc@hotmail.com");

final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(USER_URL);

httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonObj.toString()));
resp = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity ent = resp.getEntity();

result = EntityUtils.toString(ent);

JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(result);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++)
{
      JSONObject jobj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
      if (jobj.has("user_name")) 
      {
           us1 = jobj.getString("user_name");
      }
      if (jobj.has("gems_available"))
      {
           us2 = jobj.getString("gems_available");
      }
      if (jobj.has("free_gems")) 
      {
           us3 = jobj.getString("free_gems");
      }
 }
```

Comment: ["[{\"user_name\":\"\",\"gems_available\":\"10\",\"free_gems\":\"110\"},{\"match_name\":\"ausvsind\",\"Match_start_time\":\"2016-03-27 19:00:56\",\"season_name\":\"Mid-Season\"}]"]

Comment: I made slight changes to it, since a foreach loop was not supported, and the `contains` method should be `has`. I ran it with the JSON string hardcoded as the server response. The `jsonArr.toString()` did not have any backslashes in it. `us1`, `us2`, `us3` resulted in "riz", "10", "110".

Comment: sorry i am getting us2 and us3 values but not of us1

Comment: when i run the url i get username u but in the json array i did not get

Comment: Are there more json objects in the array that contain a "user_name" key? These would override the first value retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

When I have to get data from a Json, I always you serialization.

Have a Look at [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson). With it, you have to create model Objects that match the json architecture. After it, you can access all your json attributes easily.

Answer (score 0):

### There is another, better way to do this.

Use modern libraries for API calls like **Retrofit 2.0** with **GSON**.

---

1. Add **Retrofit 2.0** to your project

Read: https://github.com/square/retrofit

---

2. Create **POJO Object** from your JSON

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

- select **Source type > JSON**
- select **Annotation style > GSON**

---

3. Create API service interface

Step by step: http://square.github.io/retrofit/